# Rails: extend model with user based fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I would like to know how to handle this:

I have e.g. a table "cities" with name, population and so on, and then "last visited", "rating" and other fields, but the latter depends on the specific user. I would like to be able to use "user.cities" and then "city.name", "city.last_visited", but I wouldn't like to duplicate the fields that are not user dependent.
(E.g. User A visited Paris in 2005 and User B in 2008. "city.name" is the same, but "city.last_visited" differs)

Comment: You should read about database normalisation. This is not a Rails specific thing but a general database concept. Wikipedia describes it a little formally but still quite well http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms

Comment: Hi, it's hard to figure out what to do to help you here as you're asking a kind of broad question. Perhaps you could show us the tables you have, and what you'd hope the tables look like? Or even some pseudocode of what you'd like to see the eventual code looking like (if you could make it work any way you'd like) ?

Answer (score 0):

A city in your example has attributes that are universal (name, location), and attributes that are specific to a user's experience with or visit to the city (last_visited, visit_duration). So, what you're looking for here is a **join table**. This would contain all information about a specific user and a city. First, we'd generate a model for UserCity, which will contain all city information specific to a user.

```
rails g model UserCity user:references city:references last_visited:datetime
```

Add any other user-specific fields to this generate command for UserCity. Once you've run `rake db:migrate`, define the associations.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_cities
  has_many :cities, through: :user_cities
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_cities
  has_many :users, through: :user_cities
end
```

Be sure in your city table to only have columns that aren't specific to a single user, i.e. name. Then, to show all the cities a user has visited, and the last time they've visited that city, you can use:

```
<% user.user_cities.includes(:city).find_each do |uc| %>
  <div>
    <%= uc.city.name %>
    <%= uc.last_visited %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```